# Population growth model with fishing term (logistic differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

Hi I have following assignment and I have not really a clue on how to solve it, because it is completely different then what we did at class.

> The simple fishery model reads $\dot{N} = rN(1-N/K)-H$, where $N$ is the fish
>   population, $K$ is a carrying capacity, $r$ is the growth rate, and $H$ is the term
>   considering the effect of fishing. 
>   In a refined version, the model is improved
>   to $\dot{N}=rN(1-N/K)-H\frac{N}{A+N}$, with parameters $H$ and $A$ being larger than zero.
>
> (a) Why is the refined model more realistic than the original, simple one?
>
> (b) Give a biological interpretation of parameter $A$; what does it measure?
>
> (c) Show that the refined system can be rewritten in dimensionless form as
>   $$
> \frac{dx}{d\tau} = x(1-x) - \frac{hx}{a+x}
> $$
>
> (d) Show that the refined system can have one, two, or three fixed points,
>   depending on the numerical values of parameters $a$ and $h$. Classify the
>   stability of the fixed points.
>
> (e) Analyze the dynamics of the system near $x=0$, and show that a bifurcation occurs if $h=a$. Which kind of bifurcation is it?
>
> (f) Plot the stability diagram of the system in the $a$, $q$ parameter space.
>   Can hysteresis occur in any of the stability regions?

d and e I have some idea but with the others i am clueless :( Greetings Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Fishers cannot reduce the fish population at a constant rate $H$. If no fish is in the water, they fish nothing, i.e. the fishing term must equal zero if $N=0$. In the refined version, one can observe that the fishing rate increases with the amount of fish, but is bounded by $H$.

b) If $A=0$ the simple model is recovered. If $A\to \infty$, no fishing occurs at all. In between, the parameter $A$ sets the slope of the fishing term at $N=0$ (decreasing with $A$). Therefore, $A$ measures the inefficiency of the fishing community.

c) Let us set $t = \alpha\tau$ and $x = \beta N$. We get
$$
\frac{\text d x}{\text d \tau} = \alpha r {x} \left(1-\frac{x}{\beta K}\right) - \alpha H \frac {x}{\beta A+x} \, .
$$
Setting $\alpha =1/r$ and $\beta =1/K$, the desired equation is obtained, where $h = \alpha H$ and $a = \beta A$.

d) This question amounts to solve ${\text d x}/{\text d \tau}=0$, i.e.  $x=0$ or $x^2 + (a-1) x + h -a =0$. The solutions are $x=0$ or
$$
\begin{aligned}
x & = x_{\pm} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-a \pm \sqrt{(1+a)^2 -4h}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, we have one, two or three equilibria.

e) This question amounts to evaluate the derivative $J (x)$ of ${\text d x}/{\text d \tau}$ at the origin $x=0$. Here,
$$
J (x) = 1-2x - h \frac{a}{(a+x)^2} ,
$$
and $J (0) = 1 - h/a$. If $J (0)<0$, i.e. $h > a$, the state $x=0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium. If $h < a$ , the state $x=0$ is an unstable equilibrium. Looking back to the quadratic equation above, a pitchfork bifurcation may occur at $a = h$.

f) Now let us determine the stability of the other equilibrium points $x_{\pm}$, which exist provided that $h \leq \frac{1}{4} (1+a)^2$. The sign of $J(x_+)$ tells us that $x_+$ is asymptotically stable if $a<1$, or if $a>1$ and $h < a$. The sign of $J(x_-)$ tells us that $x_-$ is asymptotically stable if $a>1$, or if $a<1$ and $h < a$. Here are the stability diagrams in $hy, x$ space for the two cases $a<1$ and $a>1$ are provided, where $x$ is restricted to positive values:

[image: stability]

The diagrams suggest that if $a>1$ (the fishing community is not efficient), then one has only one attractive equilibrium value of $x$ simultaneously: no hysteresis occurs. However, if $a<1$ (the fishing community is more efficient), then less fish is available at equilibrium. Moreover, one has simultaneously two attractive equilibrium values for $a<h<\frac{1}{4}(1+a)^2$: hysteresis can occur.

Note that similar diagrams can be drawn in $a, x$ space.

Comment: Harr49 you are a live savior ! Do you maybee have some idea on f, i have no clue on what is ment with the stability diagram?

Comment: @MadMax I have edited my answer